# Sci-fi cartoon about robots, wars, virtual scenarios and space

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, space, robots

I only remember these facts from the series:

- Humanity is getting enslaved by another race whom seem similar to the human race
- Both groups use robots in combat
- Enemy uses technology, like a virtual mod, to see scenery, so they gain advantage in every combat encounter
- Good guys steal one of the enemy's robots and find this virtual technology
- In an episode, humanity's leader fights against the enemy leader, and the human leader wins and the enemy leaves the planet but didn't retrieve slaves because their freedom was out of the accord

Comment: See if something rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/HumongousMecha/AnimeAndManga

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a 90's cartoon Battletech (based on the mini wargame of the same name) that checks some of these boxes-

1. Humanity is enslaved by a similar race- actually the invading Clans are human or descended from humans at least.
2. Both sides pilot building-sized robots called Battlemechs.
3. Virtual mod- the clans call it enhanced visual imaging or something like that- really, just an excuse for the animators to use some funky CGI.
4. The good guys don't really steal this virtual tech, a clan warrior is captured by them and because of some strange code of honor thing shares the tech with her captors.
5. Humanity's leader defeats the invading leader- pretty much how the last episode ends IIRC.

Comment: Yeah! That's the cartoon! Thank you so much!